# figuring out what causes paintEvent with weird clipRegion in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am working on a big legacy application and there is a custom widget which is being shown on a user action. The problem is that widget is not painted because `paintEvent` for this widget comes with some weirdly small `region`. If I ignore it and paint whole widget then everything is ok, but that is just a workaround. I am trying to find a place in code which is responsible for this event but that's not an easy task.

Can you give me some tricks how can I figure out what is the source of this event?

Comment: [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) provides four flavors of `update()` (3 of them with parameters to describe a rect. or region) which have to be called if a repaint of a widget is required. These can be called in custom code, or inside of Qt code. Furthermore, there might be system events which are translated into `QPaintEvent`s. It's hard to track from which source a specific event came from because 1) an event handler is called from event loop (where the event could have been placed before into from anything) and 2) events might even be cumulated (i.e. many compressed to one).

Comment: [QEvent::spontaneous()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qevent.html#spontaneous): _Returns true if the event originated outside the application (a system event); otherwise returns false.

**The return value of this function is not defined for paint events.**_ -> Bad luck!